# In file required input use string with file content

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl

```
import socket, os
from SocketServer import BaseServer
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import ssl

class SecureHTTPServer(HTTPServer):

    def __init__(self, server_address, HandlerClass):
        BaseServer.__init__(self, server_address, HandlerClass)

        self.socket = ssl.SSLSocket(
            socket.socket(self.address_family, self.socket_type),
            keyfile = 'path\\server.key',
            certfile = 'path\\server.crt'
        )

        self.server_bind()
        self.server_activate()

class SecureHTTPRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):  

    def do_GET(self):
        #Here process response

def startServer(HandlerClass = SecureHTTPRequestHandler,
         ServerClass = SecureHTTPServer):

    server_address = ('', 8880) 
    httpd = ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass)
    sa = httpd.socket.getsockname()
    print "Serving HTTPS on", sa[0], "port", sa[1], "..."
    httpd.serve_forever()

class MainServer:   

    def __init__(self): 
        #All starts here    
        startServer()
```

I have this piece of code to start web server which ssl, actual code get certificate and key from a system path, but for security I want to store key and certificate in a String, and I want to parse to constructor function from string without using temporary files.

```
server = "Server cert here ******"    
key = "Server key here ******"
```

How I can use these variables on the first piece of code?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking exactly. Where are you defining these strings? Do you just need to know how to grab the last part of the string?

Comment: This string are defined in Python code just before first code. I need to know how to pass in the configuration of the server string containing the key and certificate instead of the files containing the key and certificate.

Comment: What makes you think your Python source code is more secure than separate `.key` and `.crt` files in the first place?

Comment: You don't show _how_ the first piece of code uses the certificate file and private key file, so how should we know what you intend to pass the contents of those files to. Are you saying that you want to store the cert and key in your Python code? How is that more secure than storing them in files?

Comment: I intend to let them encrypted and decrypt them when necessary. If they are in python code, to be distributed as an executable (.exe) to find (cert + key), would have to disassemble the exe it's more complicated to find certificates in the directory.

Comment: The function takes a path, so you can't pass in the key itself instead. And I don't think you want to.

Comment: If you embed your key and certificate in a .exe (which means that you are using py2exe or similar), what will you do when the certificate eventually expires?

Comment: @mhawake Yes, I use py2exe. My app has and automatic update system to download new version.

Comment: OK, to what are you passing the certificate and key? What library are you using, and can you show the function(s) that will be called. The reason for asking this is to see whether the receiving function(s) can actually accept a file-like object, e.g. an open file, StringIO, or some other buffer - it could be that they accept a path name only.

Comment: Embedding private keys in executables (even if obfuscated) is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the source for [`ssl.py`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/ssl.py) the certificate is loaded from a SSL context with [`SSLContext.load_cert_chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain) which the documentation states requires paths to a key file and a certificate file. I don't see any way around that such that strings or file-like objects could be passed instead.

The referenced code comes from Python 2.7.9 which includes a backport of the `ssl` module from Python 3.4, but the case is the same for earlier 2.7.x versions.

You could use temporary files, but you don't want to. You could use named pipes, but that's going to be messy.

But, since you are distributing a server, I wonder why you need to do this at all. Why don't you just have your users generate and install a certificate and key for their server? Self-signed might do, but they could have it signed by an official CA if required.

Comment: Then I try to do it as safe as possible with temporary files. The last question is a bit complicated to explain here. The certificate is same for all, is signed by CA and is used to stream media content from localhost web server to web browser that use web page (external server) that have same certificate that localhost server. The website and the local server need the same certified as the system is implemented.